# receive multiple values of a php variable in as3?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I need to receive a variable with multiple values from php in as3,

the variable is

```
$errors = "1, 4, 5"
```

but it changes the values. 
I need to take the values and ,  "read" them and depending on what values there are I'm supposed highlight corresponding fields, like errors gives me 1

```
er_1.gotoAndStop(2);
er_1.visible = true;
```

this would be easy with a simple if{} if I was receiving 1 value but I don't know how to check for multiple values, please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your values are separated by commas (or any common string), you can split a string along that comma to get an array of strings.

Example:

```
var fromPhp:String = "1, 4, 5";

// Note that it is splitting across the string ", " since 
// you have comma and a space that separates each number
var errors:Array = fromPhp.split(", ");

trace(errors.length) // prints 3, as you had 3 values
trace(errors[0]); // prints 1
trace(errors[1]); // prints 4
trace(errors[2]); // prints 5
```

Note that all the values inside error are still strings, so you may need to parse them back into ints.

Comment: minus of the split in this example is by adding the space to the delimiter - then you have to be careful to actualy have it in the string from PHP e.g. "1,4,5" will return array of length 1 with errors[0] = "1,4,5";

Comment: thank you but, 1, 4 , 5 arent the values, the values change, it could be from 1 to 9 (1, 2, 3, ... ,9) or it even could be empty. also I'll have to check what values is it giving me, like if there is a 9 in it or so. can you help me?

Comment: Yes, as Lukasz mentioned, the key is making sure the separating string (delimiter) matches from the php. The length of values is not an issue whether it is 3 or 9 or 50 or 100 values. The length of the array would change depending on the number of values from the split() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive the single value as a String, then split the String into an array.

```
var receivedValue:String = ev.target.data;
arrayOfErrors:Array = receivedValue.split(",");

trace(arrayOfErrors[0]);
//traces 1
```